# Internet Explorer CSS Issue

Tags: css, cross-browser

So I'm attempting to figure out where my cross-compatibility issue is - From what I can tell, Firefox and Safari have been working great, however Internet Explorer (surprise?) has been giving me tons of issues.  Take a look at the site below:

https://secure.promptpass.com/index.php?clinic=1

For some reason, the background image is over-extending itself on the top and bottom (if you open the website, you will immediately understand what I mean).

Beyond that, in the Select box next to the "Select a Time" label, to the right there is always a box filled with ":45 pm".

The last remaining issue is that the entire content of this on many versions of Internet Explorer, all of the content is shifted to the left - based on the CSS, everything should be centered

Again, I've poured over this (and I'm sure these are simple things that I have overlooked) however at this point, I'm at a loss as to what this issue would be.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: A sample of what Internet Explorer makes this look like compared to other browsers can be found here: http://browsershots.org/https://secure.promptpass.com/index.php?clinic=2#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move this elsewhere:

```
<!-- Google Website Optimizer Control Script --> 
<script> 
function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}
(function(){var k='2883663228',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;function f(n){
if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.indexOf(';',i);return c.substring(i+n.
length+1,j<0?c.length:j)}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;
d.write('<sc'+'ript src="'+
'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':'://www')+'.google-analytics.com'
+'/siteopt.js?v=1&utmxkey='+k+'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='
+new Date().valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></sc'+'ript>')})();
</script> 
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Control Script -->
```

It makes the page render in quirks mode as opposed to standards mode so IE is rendering it in super-retarded mode and in this, [margin:0 auto doesn't work in IE quirks](http://work.arounds.org/issue/25/margin-0-auto-doesnt-center-ie/). The doctype will make it render in standards mode.

Comment: If we weren't communicating across a series of tubes known as the internet, and were instead in a room, seated at a table, I would leap over that table and give you a big wet kiss.  Thank you SO MUCH - I didn't realize Google Website Optimizer could cause issues like this.  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: well it's mostly the location of the code, not the code itself. I imagine if you throw it before the end body tag it'd be fine. After making this change, are you still experiencing issues other than the centering?

Comment: I took a second look, both on a different machine and redoing browsershots.org, and they both seem to confirm that my issue was with the Google Website Optimizer code.  Thanks again!